# Как положить лямбду в List<Task>

Tags: c#

Есть список задач `List<Task>`.

Не могу разобраться как правильно положить в него лямбду. 
Таким образом как у меня сейчас отрабатывает неправильно и на консоль выводится только "one";

Почему вторая таска не отрабатывает?

```
static void Main()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    tasks.Add(TestMethod("one"));
    tasks.Add(new Task(async () => await TestMethod("two")));
    Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static async Task TestMethod(string msg)
{
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

Comment: Task.WhenAll(tasks) лишь создаёт задачу, дожидающуюся данных двух. Но не _дожидается_ их.

Comment: Влад прав. Либо делайте ассинхронным `Main` и добавляйте `await` перед этим, либо используйте `Task.WaitAll()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все верно. Вы же её **создали**, но **не запустили**. Чтобы вторая отработала - запускайте ее с помощью [`Task.Run()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => await TestMethod("two")));
```

[Тестить](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qFSG75)!

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/

Comment: @VladD черт, верно. Вы правы :)